# How to go from given incidences in 24 years to annual probability?

Tags: probability, self-study, binomial-distribution, poisson-binomial-distribution

For a biostatistics class, I have to determine the annual probability of at least one heart attack for various groups of given data that was collected over a period of 24 years. I won't put all the data here as there are several "risk factors" in tables, but for the sake of example, I'll use incidence of heart attack by relative weight.

So for men that fell in the age group 30-39, and had a relative weight score of 80-89, the 24 year incidence of at least 1 heart attack was 101 per 1,000 individuals in that category (The weight score is based on 100 being median weight, 80 being 20% below median weight, but that's not important here).

I need to go from 101/1000 in a 24 year span to what the probability of a heart attack would be annually, but I don't know how to get there. I know if I was given an annual probability p, I could do (1-p)^x years to find the likelihood of it not happening in x years, but I don't know how to go backwards. I also don't know if I should be using a binomial model or Poisson, but I know it has to be one of them because in the question I'm told to consider having a heart attack as a success.

Edit: Found out from the professor that I can find annual probability using the equation

$1-f=e^{-24p} $

Where f is the frequency in 24 years, so 101/1000, and solve for p, which looks like

$p=\frac{ln(1-f)}{-24}$

Comment: What are the formal assumptions of the Poisson distribution? One of them pretty directly addresses your question. (Also: Welcome! :)

Comment: @Alexis I had to look up the assumptions because my professor didn't talk about some of them...so I don't exactly know which one you're talking about. My guess is that "The probability of an event within a certain interval does not change over different intervals" is what applies to my situation, but wouldn't that mean that the probability in a year would be the same as the 24 year data?

Comment: I honestly don't understand why this is being voted to close as off-topic. I am asking about these votes in chat and would appreciate someone explaining to and enlightening me: https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/42934917#42934917

Comment: It's unclear how to interpret your solution.  It's based on an assumption of independence, but is that realistic for your 24 years of data?  E.g., is the "24 year incidence of heart attack" for the male 30-39 y.o. group the rate of heart attacks occurring to males when their age is between 30 and 40 or would it be the proportion of males aged 30-40 who had a heart attack during the last 24 years?

Comment: @whuber for ease of calculations, the professor said to consider it independent. In reality, you're right, it probably isn't independent. The data we were given was the incidence reported in 24 years for each group.